# How to install the 3part django app using pip on Openshift

Tags: django, pip, openshift

Thank for your help at first
I created a app on Openshift (create method pls
 refer to https://github.com/drivard/openshift-django-mysql)
Now i want to install pip and a 3part app(such as hitconter), my steps as follow:
1. ssh to remote host
2. cd $OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR
3. wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.1.tar.gz
4. tar zxf pip-1.1.tar.gz
5. cd pip-1.1
6. python setup.py install (shell mentioned no write permission)

So how can I install pip and use pip to install app in Openshift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add required apps to `setup.py` file . For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='YourAppName',
    version='1.0',
    description='OpenShift App',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='example@example.com',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    # Your 3part apps:
    install_requires=['Django>=1.3', 'pil', 'south'],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, there is another is how can I check the app is installed correctly or not? I tried in remote python shell with command 'import pil', but it is failed.

Comment: @vikingyang With the python shell, if you are testing the import, it should be 'import PIL' allcaps on PIL.